# Java Maven repository settings.xml

Tags: cloudcontrol

I successfully added a private repository to my `pom.xml` with credentials in `settings.xml`
and locally the build works fine (with a cleared cache - just to be sure).

**But how would I pass the `settings.xml` entries to `cctrlapp APP_NAME/dev push`?**

The build fails due to failing authentication against the private repository (Bitbucket in this case): the downloads contain a 401 resonse HTML "Please log in".

I investigated for the `system.properties` as well as the log

```
-----> executing /srv/tmp/buildpack-cache/.maven/bin/mvn -B 
-Duser.home=/srv/tmp/builddir 
-Dmaven.repo.local=/srv/tmp/buildpack-cache/.m2/repository 
-s /srv/tmp/buildpack-cache/.m2/settings.xml 
-DskipTests=true clean install
```

which does not seem an option for overriding.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We provide the public key specific to your app in the application details. By adding this to Bitbucket (or any repository service supporting access via SSH) and specifying SSH when accessing the private repository the platform will be able to authenticate using the private key.

```
$ cctrlapp APP_NAME details # will show the public key
```